# jQuery File Upload загрузка файлов любых типов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, где в плагине jQuery-File-Upload разрешить загрузку файлов pdf ?
Пробовал добавлять в файле jquery.fileupload-image.js, но не помогло(

Comment: Там есть option - acceptFileTypes

Comment: @InDevX в файле demo.js есть такая опция, но она тоже не пропускает формат